# Conditional independence, is $P(A|C) = \sum_{B} P(A,B|C)$

Tags: probability

The following holds true $$P(A) = \sum_{B} P(A,B)$$ if we have a condition does it still hold true
$$P(A|C) = \sum_{B} P(A,B|C)$$

Comment: Yes! Just write out what $P(A|C) $ means and you see it!

Comment: @Shashi thank you I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does.

$$\frac{P(A,C)}{P(C)} = \sum_B \frac{P(A,B,C)}{P(C)}$$

$$P(A,C)=\sum_BP(A,B,C)$$